# Freshly Pitched Yeast at top of Must

Tags: mead

I'm making some homemade mead and I just pitched my yeast. My must has quite the gradient to it. The top is a light brown where the yeast is then it fades to golden toward the bottom. Should I attempt to mix it or is it probably okay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing your recipe, I would say leave it alone.   Probably just a matter of some particulates in the must weighing  more than others.  I think two things will happen: (1) the yeast will probably stir things up and (2) as it ferments the liquid will clear anyway and particulates will settle at the bottom of the vessel.

In my view, the risk of infection with stirring generally exceeds any probability of benefit.